# Erro ao instalar React

Tags: javascript, react

Estou tentando instalar reagir mas quando eu digito o comando:

> npm install -g criar-reagir-app

ele me retorna um erro Por favor me ajude a entender o motivo que eu recebo esse erro

Comment: Você tem o NPM instalado? O comando não seria `npm install -g create-react-app`? Ajudaria se você postasse qual erro está recebendo.

Comment: Seu comando está em português

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comando que você digitou está em português, tente novamente, porém em inglês:

```
npm i -g create-react-app
```